# How to Send Lead Form Data to swaggerhub Api using php?

Tags: php, html, web, postman, swaggerhub

I have a Swagger API on which, I had to send Lead Form Data From my Web Page. I Can't Get much data From internet. Form is Already Created on Swagger HUB on Which ,I can manually insert data and it's Working But I had to send data From my Webpage , I am Already sending Data From my Webpage to Google Sheets But I Can't insert same data into Swagger HUB API Dynamically Can Anyone Help me With it Thanks!

Comment: Please add the api details

Comment: https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis-docs/AdvertisingClub/BRM/1.0.1#/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation you have to use formdata to send infomration:

[image]

First you have to authenticate using authenticate endpoint and then use that token for authenticating the post endpoint.

[image]

Comment: Sir ! Please tell me how I can post data here using php